# Elastomer vs metal spring

Tags: spring

What properties should an elastomer have for it to be used as a spring?

I mean: if I load a metal-coiled spring within the spring's elastic limits and then remove the load, then the metal spring would quickly return back to its original shape/position. I don't know what this property is called in engineering terms, but let's call it response time.

So if we similarly load an elastomer and then remove the load, will it have similar response times as a metal spring ?

Comment: Hint: the elastomer should be something that can be modeled with the same equation that is used to model a spring.

Comment: @DavidWhite Elastometers are usually modeled as viscoelastic materials, while springs are purley elastic. So the relaxation time after the load is removed can be wildly different.

Comment: @lavirtuosacorcholatavoladora, the OP didn't ask what properties an elastomer  has, he asked what properties SHOULD an elastomer have if it is to be used as a spring.

Comment: @DavidWhite great! I can look into a spring model

Comment: @lavirtuosacorcholatavoladora so it the term of called `relaxation time`

Comment: A reference on how to choose materials properties for mechanical design is [Ashby Materials Selection in Mechanical Design](https://www.elsevier.com/books/materials-selection-in-mechanical-design/ashby/978-0-08-095223-9).

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer thanks for the fabulous link, highly appreciated.

Comment: Additionally, my question was mainly about speed of reaction after the load is removed from the object.For. eg. a metal spring quickly returns to its position after removal of load. How long would elastomers take. Is there any data available regarding this?